# Constraints of Contact Forces

Tags: special-relativity, forces, speed-of-light, causality, interactions

Are contact forces limited to the speed of light like non-contact forces like gravity? If I took an infinitely long newton's cradle and placed in a vacuum with zero energy loss, would the time between applying force on one side and the force reaching the other side be zero?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that *every* transmission of information or energy is limited to the speed of light in vacuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of contact forces is often related to the speed of sound in the material. The propagation of contact forces needs the deformation in the media, and the sound waves are caused by the same mechanism. For example, the compressional and transverse seismic waves have different speed, which corresponds to the speed of sound for two kinds of contact force being propagated in the earthquake.

For the infinitely long newton's cradle, the speed is just the speed of sound in the material, say iron or copper or whatever.